# Ruby curb on Windows: I installed 0.7.12, bundler complains not being able to install 0.7.10

Tags: ruby, curb

I got this error when calling "bundle update":

> Installing curb (0.7.10) with native
>   extensions
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in
>   `rescue in block in build_extensions':
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> ```
>     C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb  checking for
> ```
>
> curl-config... no checking for main()
>   in -lcurl... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
>   file for more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
>     --with-curl-dir     --without-curl-dir
>     --with-curl-include
>     --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
>     --with-curl-lib
>     --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
>     --with-curllib  --without-curllib
>   extconf.rb:23:in `':   Can't
>   find libcurl or curl/curl.h
>   (RuntimeError)
>
> Try passing --with-curl-dir or
>   --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include   options to extconf.

Then [installed](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/KERNDOC/How+to+install+curl,+ruby,+and+the+rubygem+libraries+%28curb+and+json%29+onto+a+windows+xp+machine) the latest curb version (0.7.12) by myself using DevKit and I can see it on "gem list". However, the bundler still throws the same error trying to install curb 0.7.10 (older version), even though I haven't mentioned "curb" anywhere in my Gemfile.

Where is the problem and how do I solve it?

Windows 7, Ruby 1.92, Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Just "bundle update curb".